# Is this api restful?

Tags: api, rest, sugarcrm

I'm trying to wrap my head around creating a restful api that reads, creates, updates, and deletes multiple records at a time. I came across SugarCRM's "restful" api and the examples they provide.

I have no idea what is considered restful about their api in their example. All of the requests to the api are **post**'ed via cURL. Retrieving records uses a cURL **post**(shouldn't they be using **get**?).

Is their api considered restful? and if so how?

[Their example retrieving multiple records](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/100Web_Services/100REST_API/100Examples/100PHP/Retrieving_a_list_of_records_-_REST_and_PHP)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current SugarCRM REST API in 6.5 is definitely not RESTful, it is more RPC based. The new one coming over the coming months will be more RESTful however.

See Wikipedia for a better guide here...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer